# Ошибка в коде программы. Для каждого символа указать относительную частоту

Tags: pascal

Дана задача: Для каждого символа заданного текста указать его относительную частоту появления в тексте. Построить соответствующую диаграмму. Сообщение об одном символе должно печататься не более одного раза.

Вот мой черновик. Программа читает текст из файла, который может состоять из любого количества символов(английские , русские буквы, всевозможные знаки препинания и все это в несколько строк), выводить нужно только символы-буквы. всё шло прекрасно до того момента как текст состоял из двух-трёх строк, но если читать ,к примеру, полноценное стихотворение, то начинаются ошибки(выводит несколько раз сообщение об одинаковых символах, некоторые буквы не выводит вовсе, неправильно считает) и как мне уже подсказали формула по которой считается относительная частота не верна(.до диаграммы дело не доходит так понимаю, что смысла нет за неё браться пока происходят вот такие косяки..

Прошу посмотреть программу и помочь с выявлением ошибок

```
Program chast;

uses crt;

var
  t: text;
  s: string;
  a: array [0 .. 255] of integer;
  k, b, i, max: integer;

BEGIN
  clrscr;
  k := 0;
  assign(t, 'int.pas');
  reset(t);
  while not(eof(t)) do
  begin

    readln(t, s);
    for i := 1 to length(s) do
    begin
      inc(k);
      case ord(s[i]) of
        97 .. 122, 224 .. 255:
          inc(a[ord(s[i])]);
        65 .. 90, 128 .. 159:
          begin
            s[i] := chr(ord(s[i]) + 32);
            inc(a[ord(s[i])]);
          end;
      end;
    end;

    writeln('Относительная частота повторений символов в тексте');
    writeln;
    max := 0;
    for i := 32 to 255 do
      if a[i] <> 0 then
      begin
        writeln(chr(i), ' - частота ', (a[i] / 100 * k):3:2, '% встречается в тексте ', a[i], ' раз(а)');
        if a[i] > max then
        begin
          max := a[i];
          b := i
        end;
      end;
  end;
  writeln;
  writeln;
  writeln('всего символов - ', k, '  больше всего встречается - ''', chr(b), '''  ', max, ' раз(а)');
  close(t);
  readln;
END.
```

Comment: @student___, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 3):

Мне, если честно, проще написать все заново, чем разбираться в Вашем коде. Тем более не комментированном.

Попробуйте взять бумажку и проанализировать свой алгоритм. Скорее всего ошибка в нем. Если ошибки Вы не нашли - проверьте код. Советую разбить его на функции. Я бы сделал функцию `is_letter`, которая получает символ и возвращает `False`, если это не буква и `True`, если это буква. Еще советую использовать стандартные функции типа UpperCase и т. п., они сильно упрощают жизнь, ибо `s[i]:=chr(ord(s[i])+32);` - выглядит ужасно.